# map javascript api with ionic2 not working well

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, ionic2

I'm using map javascript API with ionic2 , everything work well first time i enter the form where the map is, but if i go back and then return to the same form where the map located, the map don't appear, just the icon of [] of full screen and google word appear, i don't know why?
When i open the full map it appear normally. something weird.

```
 export class MapPage {

  @ViewChild('mapCanvas') mapElement: ElementRef;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });
  }


  public loadMap() {
    let mapEle = this.mapElement.nativeElement;
    let currentLocation = { lat: 34.5419832, lng: 36.0633188 };
    let map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, {
      center: currentLocation,
      zoom: 16
    });
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
<ion-content padding>
<div style="height: 50%; width: 100%" #mapCanvas id="map_canvas"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

i sloved it by add this code :

```
setTimeout(() =>{
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
      }, 600);
```

after declaration of the map in the load function.

Comment: Rather than using `setTimeout` you should use the life-cycle hooks because you can't guarantee if the elements are going to be created in 600ms.